# Ruby: Save class/method definitions at runtime

Tags: ruby, introspection

So let's say I'm working in IRB, experimenting and gradually building some new classes and methods.  Or, let's say that a regular script I write (outside IRB) builds some classes/methods progressively.

Now I want to save what I have built.

Is there an easy way to automatically introspect the runtime's classes/methods and turn them into ordinary class definitions and method definitions?

Comment: I don't know any way to do this. But to be honest that sounds really interesting and should be possible. I won't use it to develop with IRB, though. I'd really love to create some "intelligent" and "learning" code.

Answer (score 1):

Try [pry](http://pry.github.com/), you'll never come back to IRB. You can use pry as a debugger, it works very well and has some great features like:

```
1.9.2 (main):0 > show-method Array#group_by

From: enum.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 13

static VALUE
enum_group_by(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE hash;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(obj, 0, 0);

    hash = rb_hash_new();
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, group_by_i, hash);
    OBJ_INFECT(hash, obj);

    return hash;
}
```

Is has the [edit-method](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration#wiki-Edit_method) command too. Imagine what you can do with it.

If you want a strictly IRB-related solution the only thing that come to my mind is [sketches](http://sketches.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on ruby 1.8, you can use [ruby2ruby](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby2ruby) for that.

Otherwise, maybe [sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify) will help. Seems it only works for methods, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Pry](http://pry.github.com) instead of IRB you can do this, in fact Pry was somewhat designed for this.

Look into the `edit-method` and `edit` Pry commands, here: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration

Also watch the screencast found here: http://vimeo.com/26391171